# What is this Android Snippet doing?

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout, tablerow

EDIT** Figured out my own answers except for my major question as follows:

```
            TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);

            TableRow row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
            row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            // inner for loop
            for (int j = 1; j <= courseHoleCount; j++) {
                 **TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));**
                tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
                tv.setTextSize(30);
                tv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                tv.setText(String.valueOf(players[i-1].getScore()[j-1]));// (-1) because j = 1 and not 0.
                row.addView(tv);
            }
            tableLayout.addView(row);


            linearLayout.addView(tableLayout);
```

In the above code snippet, what does this do and what/why are TableRow.Layout params being added to a text view layout param?

```
tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: I basically ended up copying and pasting the programatic portion of the code generation and got it duplicated, but I still do not know why I can't achieve the same results through the XML. I'm still confused as to what the line of code with the **'s are doing.

Comment: can you give screen shot? just to figure out what is you want to achieve

Comment: @ntaloventi I completely re-did my question for what's applicable now. I got everything else I needed set through changing my requirements and working things through. Just need/want to know what the bottom snippet is doing and what it means with the topmost snippet being the context (or close to it).

Comment: Please edit your title to describe the technical issue of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TableRow.LayoutParams` are being used because `tv` is a child of `row` which is a `TableRow`.
If you look at the [Android API reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)), it says

> Set the layout parameters associated with this view. These supply parameters to the parent of this view specifying how it should be arranged.

And the two parameters for the `LayoutParams` constructor are used to set the width and height of `tv`. Since both width and height is set to `WRAP_CONTENT`, the size of `tv` [will be big enough to enclose its content (plus padding)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html).

Answer (score 0):

The `TextView`'s parent is a `TableRow`, therefore the `TextView`s layout params should be of type `TableRow.LayoutParams`.

This is the exact same as specifying:

```
<TableRow ...>
    <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</TableRow>
```

If the `TextView` was added to some other `ViewGroup` like a `LinearLayout` then it would need `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` set.

Comment: Thank you, the xml reference helped a lot!